# Querying states/properties of datatables embedded in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

I have a [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/) interfaced/created via [`DT::datatable`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and rendered via [`DT::renderDataTable`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/).

How do I query a datatable's states/properties in order to use these for the design of reactive UI components?

For a particular example: how do I query the value of the `iDisplayLength` property that a user selected (AFAIU, that controls how many elements/rows are shown)?

I would like to use that value in the following way (PSEUDO CODE):

```
if (iDisplayLength != "All") {
  do not enable vertical scrolling
} else {
  enable vertical scrolling
}
```

Because of the vertical scrolling part, the question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548209/conditional-vertical-scrolling-in-datatables-embedded-in-a-shiny-app) where you'll find an actual example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the length of the pages selected by the user using `input$tableId_state$length`. You need to set the `stateSave` option to `TRUE` for this to work, see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), section 2.2.

Here's a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(textOutput("pageLength"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))
  ,
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris,options=list(stateSave=TRUE)
    )
    output$pageLength = renderText(paste("Lenght of the pages:",input$tbl_state$length))
    })
  }
)
```

If you need this value for something else, you can always store it in a reactive value.